# Python encode base64 not expect right result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I am writing a base64 encoding method to convert big integer to base64. However, when I test my method I find result is strange. While `encode_b64(int('908540701891980503'))` method gave me `ybyPRoQW0X`, however I expect the right `ybyPRoQWzX`.

```
def encode_b64(n):
    table = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    result = []
    temp = n
    if 0 == temp:
        return '0'
    else:
        while 0 < temp:
            idx = temp % 64
            result.append(table[idx])
            temp /= 64
            temp = int(temp)
    return ''.join([x for x in reversed(result)])
```

I have checked several time, but I cannot found logical error. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic integer division issue

In python2 `temp /= 64` would perform integer division and so your code would work fine. But it in python3, this would result in a float.

To fix the issue in python3, change `temp /= 64` to `temp //= 64` to force integer division and get rid of the `temp = int(temp)` line

Answer (score 2):

You should use *integer division* here, so `temp //= 64` instead of `temp /= 64`.

```
def encode_b64(n):
    table = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    if not n:
        return 'A'
    result = []
    while n:
        result.append(table[n % 64])
        n //= 64
    return ''.join(reversed(result))
```

this gives us:

```
>>> encode_b64(908540701891980503)
'ybyPRoQWzX'
```

For small numbers, that will not make a difference, but large floating point numbers have rounding errors, and thus using `int(..)` might give slightly different results.

If you want to optimize the above a but further, you can use bitwise operations, like:

```
def encode_b64(n):
    table = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    if not n:
        return 'A'
    result = []
    while n:
        result.append(table[n & 0x3f])
        n >>= 6
    return ''.join(reversed(result))
```